# How to make an EditText selectable but not editable on Android Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a ListView in Activity, and in each item , I insert an EditText for show my text.
I need drag the handle to select text & copy the text, but can not edit text.
On Android ICS, How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
Just set TextView like this:

```
text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Answer (score 23):

`text.setTextIsSelectable(true)` requires API 11. For those using lower API's:
In xml use:

```
android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

This will make your EditText uneditable but selectable.

Comment: I can confirm that on API 10 (tested on 2.3.4 and 2.3.6) the above two lines doesn't work. The EditText is still editable and the keyboard pops out..

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: Check out my full answer posted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20173020/1241783. Not very proud of the hacky way but it is the only way that I know of for now. Do let me know if someone knows a better way for API version < 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you could override the onKeyDown() method, make it do nothing but return true. It should catch the keypresses from the keyboard and negate them before they can go into the text in the EditText.

You might also [try setting editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aeditable) to false like this

```
android:editable="false"
```

on the EditText in your xml layout. However I am not certain if this will let you still highlight and copy, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! But android:editable is deprecated on Android Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: did they leave a note that tells you what to use instead?

Comment: Yes, they told me use TextView instead. But TextView can not be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Althouth `android:editable` is **deprecated** and Lint suggests to use `inputType`, It doesn't seem to work. So `android:editable="false"`is apparently the best possible solution for all android versions.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    tools:ignore="Deprecated" />
```