# colorPrimaryDark is not applying for particular activity in Status Bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

For information, I am using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 7, API 23.

Activity that is having the issue
[image: Activity that doesn't apply the theme]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="in.ezyride.blovia.OfferRide"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/view">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view">
        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/basicLayoutAddl"
            layout="@layout/content_offer_ride"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But other activities are regular. This happened when I was trying to fix the keyboard covering EditText issue. However I almost solved that, new one raised.

For fixing it, I added scroll view in the above relative layout.

The manifest part of the activity is as follows

```
<activity
android:name=".OfferRide"
android:label="@string/title_activity_offer_ride"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Other activity where things are normal.
[image]

File: styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="md_positive_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_neutral_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_title_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_negative_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_widget_color">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: Could you please add your styles too?

Comment: @LinX64 sure just a min..

Comment: What are the contents of `content_offer_ride` ? what is the root tag? it should fixed with my answer anyways.

Comment: @LinX64 root tag of `content_offer_ride` is `RelativeLayout`

Comment: So, it should be fixed with adding the parent since you have Toolbar in your styles.see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

> `AppBarLayout` is a `vertical LinearLayout` which implements many of the
>   features of material designs app bar concept, namely scrolling
>   gestures.
>
> Children should provide their desired scrolling behavior through
>   setScrollFlags(int) and the associated layout xml attribute:
>   app:layout_scrollFlags.
>
> This view depends heavily on being used **as a direct child within a
>   CoordinatorLayout**

Use `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and instead of `ScrollView`, Use `NestedScrollView`.

And change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Since you already have `Toolbar`, let's imagine you've already added this in your `OnCreate`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Now the issue is, I am having a `EditText` on the `content_offer_ride` which is being covered on by the soft keyboard. Please help for that!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174606/disable-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-but-still-allow-copy-paste

Comment: When `EditText` gets focus, the Keyboard covers it. So I cannot see what is being typed while typing!

Comment: You need to use Ask question for opening new topic about it with your layout contents, i can't help you without seeing that layout :)

Comment: That's it, i'll check it.Thank you for following the rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101507/discussion-between-sibidharan-and-linx64).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was because I had two files styles.xml in my project, in both of them had the same name of theme for the activities.
Let me describe it.

This is my activity in the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

[image]

This is my first **styles.xml** (default):

[image]

This is my second **styles.xml** (V21):

[image]

The app in running mode used the second style, it had the problem, because we couldn't see the **colorPrimaryDark** of the app.

The solution was, comment the last item in the second style.xml:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was windowTranslucentStatus:

Before:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/bright_purple</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

After:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/bright_purple</item>
            <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDarkBlue</item>
```