# Android - EditText- selectable, uneditable

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have been developing a simple Calculator Application in Android Studio.
The result window (where the numbers are placed for calculation) I initially set as a TextView. However, I haven't found a way to implement a cursor while using the TextView. My goal is to have the result window display a cursor and have text selectable but not editable. When using EditView I have tried to disable the soft keyboard, disable input, etc., with no success. Can I accomplish this using either an EditView/TextView?

Soft keyboard issue
[image]

Screenshot
[image]

I obviously do not want the user to be able to utilize the soft keyboard, but I still want to maintain the cursor and have the text selectable.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174606/disable-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-but-still-allow-copy-paste

Comment: to be clear you want that softkeys should not pop up when you click on edittext ?

Answer (score 1):

To hide keyboard keys in fragment interface use

```
EditText edt=(EditText)View.findViewById(R.id.editTextForNumbers);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

If it is in an activity use

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextForNumbers);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This was implemented but still results in the soft keyboard popping up when text is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties for your edittext or textview

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173020/1617737