# Android copy text from disable edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having a disabled Edittext and now i want to give the select and copy functionality on it. is it possible with disabled edittext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulled from: [How to make an EditText selectable but not editable on Android Ice Cream Sandwich?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544315/resolvedhow-to-make-an-edittext-selectable-but-not-editable-on-android-ice-cre).

If you have API below 11 use the following code in your edittext XML:

```
android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

if API is 11 or above use the following java:

```
edittext.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: I can confirm that on API 10 (tested on 2.3.4 and 2.3.6) the above two lines doesn't work. The EditText is still editable and the keyboard pops out..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TextView` instead of disabled `EditText` and try [`android:textIsSelectable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextIsSelectable).
If you are targetting old API then you can attach a click listener on `TextView` and in `onClick` just do:

```
ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
cm.setText(textView.getText());
Toast.makeText(context, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and then later somewhere:

```
String copiedText = cm.getText();
```

Also for more advanced implementation please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html